# Addin outlook 2013 do not show when reply email

Tags: outlook-addin, ribbon

When I write an outlook addin with ribbon. I add a new group to tab 'MESSAGE'. It work when I Create new Email with Popup. But it does not work when reply Email.

Here is my source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabNewMailMessage">
        <group id="MyGroup"
               label="My Group">
        </group>
      </tab>
      <tab idMso="TabReadMessage">
        <group id="MyGroup1"
               label="My Group1">
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: I solved this problem. It is not work because in Outlook 2013 has "Compose Tools". To  as control to this using this source
 <code>

Answer (score 1):

Do you get any UI errors in Outlook? See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) for more information.

There is no TabReadMessage, you need to use TabNewMailMessage instead. But not together in the same context.

You need to return the XML markup of your custom ribbon UI in the GetCustomUI method of the IRibbonExtensibility interface for the appropriate context only. See [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)